# How to lift from 2013 to 2015?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I might be slow or something but I can only find RU1 to CRM 2013. Where can I find the upgrade (not a full installer) to lift from 2013 to 2015? I've got one since before but after some confusion and a case of "too many cooks in the kitchen", it claims that it can't perform.

Where do I get the official upgrade from 2013 to 2015?

(Yes, I've googled for it. I get a lot but not the actual binaries from MS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade from CRM 2013 to CRM 2015 you need to install Service Pack 1 on the CRM 2013 server. Then, there are three options to do an upgrade, which is describet in the Implementation Guide for CRM 2015 and in short consists of the following steps:

1. In-place upgrade, pop the 2015 installation media on the existing server and run it.
2. New CRM server same SQL, install a new CRM server and point it to the old SQL server
3. Migration, install a new system with both CRM and SQL, then restore the ORG_MSCRM on the SQL server and import the organization using the deployment administration tool.

You have more info [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699716.aspx), and there's also more info in the [IG](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45022)

Comment: SP1 is installed. However, I can't find the actual binaries to run for the update. I only find the binaries for **installation** and not the **lift form 2013**. Is that the same installation package?

Comment: Yes, you use the install package to upgrade. Read through the upgrade part of the IG and things will be clearer i hope

Comment: Awesome! I was chicken poo all for nothing. Thanks.